# Sharepoint 2013 farm administrator password

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Hope everyone is doing fine.

Actually I need to know can we change the sharepoint farm administrator password?
I have researched and got to know that it can be change easily, but it's also recommended that change it first in testing environment.

Unfortunately we have a testing environment but if we change password there it reflects in production as well because we have only one active directory server for all the servers.

Our public facing website has developed on sharepoint 2013 and daily we get more than 120,000 visitors.

So please by keeping our visitors in mind suggest me what to do,
If can be change I would highly appreciate if anyone can guide me through the process.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**by keeping your visitors in mind**, in the normal case, the changing password process should not require an outage , meanwhile, at Production environment , you should apply it out working hour.

My suggestion is to apply this process first at Test, but in your case, the services account is the same in both environments , so you should care of that.

also, Try to list all application services , application pool , windows service and SQL services and make sure it's working and up running after changing the password .

Here you can find all possible issues that may face you and how to overcome it [Managing Passwords for Service Accounts in SharePoint & SQL Server](https://blog.zubairalexander.com/managing-passwords-for-service-accounts-in-sharepoint-sql-server/)

**The following are the required steps in normal scenario :**

1. Navigate to SharePoint 2013 Central Administration interface, click Security in the left-hand menu, and click ‘Configure Managed Accounts’.  Select the farm administrators to account in the account list shown, click the Edit icon and change the password.
2. Manually change the User Profile Service password.  As required by SharePoint, this service uses the farm administrator account, however, SharePoint 2013 does not treat this account as a managed account so it must be changed manually.
3. Check if any applications in the Secure Store service use the farm administrator account, and if they do change the password there.
4. Reboot all the servers in the SharePoint farm, except for SQL server.  SQL Server does not need to be restarted.

For more details check Step by Step: [Changing the SharePoint 2013 Farm Account Password](http://www.trustsharepoint.com/2015/06/step-by-step-changing-sharepoint-2013.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but may I please know a little more about 3rd point that you mentioned??

Comment: this depends on Have you configured Secure Store service or not ,  Secure Store service is an application service that provides storage and mapping of credentials such as account names and passwords. It enables you to securely store data that provides credentials required for connecting to external systems and associating those credentials to a specific identity or group of identities. so maybe you have store thisis account that you need to change its password in this service so you will need to update its password with the new password ,

Comment: Additionally To know how to check this Launch SharePoint Central Admin, click Application Management in the left hand menu, click Manage Service Applications, click the Secure Store Application and click Manage Target Applications. for more details check this http://www.trustsharepoint.com/2015/06/step-by-step-changing-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: Hi @Asrar please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification , also should you check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to got informed badge

Comment: Dear Sir, 
Thank you so much for such amazing tips.
I will be going to work on it either today or tomorrow.
I will update you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SharePoint Central Administration and select Security -> Configure Managed Accounts and click on the Edit button against the respective Service Account for which the password needs to be updated. Once the Edit page loads, click on "Use existing password". By doing this, the account will use the AD password.

[image]

Below is the powershell code for the above use case:

```
$ManagedAccount = Read-Host "Enter the Managed account in Domain\User Format:"

#Get new Password for the managed account
$Password = Read-Host "Enter new password for managed account" –AsSecureString

#Change the password for the managed account
Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $ManagedAccount -ExistingPassword $Password -UseExistingPassword $true
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

May I please know will we have to face with any problems after changing the password??

Comment: couple of things you can keep in mind - 1) If you get  "The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements" - use the password as per your AD policy.  2) If you face  "Access denied" - make sure "User cannot change password" is not checked in AD.

Answer (score 0):

Hi through following command you change the farm account

```
STSADM.EXE -o updatefarmcredentials -userlogin "domain\username " -password "#####"
```